# What is the time complexity of sorting alg when the compare function is not O(1)?

Tags: time-complexity

As I know an efficient sorting alg time complexity is `O(N*log(N))` when the compare function is `O(1)`.

If the compare function is not `O(1)` (i.e `O(M)`), what is the time complexity?

Is it `O(N*log(N*M))` or `O(N*M*log(N))`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each compare takes O(M) time -- as oppose to O(1) time then the whole sort will take M times longer to complete -- O(M * N log N). This is assuming that M grows with N and is not constant.  Constants are typically dropped from big Oh notation ( O(constant) == O(1) ) so the complexity in this case would be unchanged.  This also assumes that your O(Y) sort algorithm does on the order of O(Y) compares as most sorting algorithms do.

Answer (score 0):

in efficent sorting alg we have `(N)` items and for each item 
we have `O(LOG N)` comparison .that result for sorting is : `O(N* LOG N)`.
if comparison be `O(1)` we have : `O(1*N)`  = `O(N)` for sort.

it is possible in parallel sorting alg on parallel computer architectures.
but in unparalel computers it is not possible for have `O(1*N)`